# How to change text from java code?

Tags: android

Excuse me if this is an easy problem. I have been unable to find an answer so far.I have followed this tutorial( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fn5OlqQuOCk ) to create a pop up window. While it works as intended I want to change the text when the button is pressed from the java code.

To be more specific, I have a string array and whenever the button is pressed I want it to show a random element of the array. How can I go about doing those things?

My onCreate method is(mundaneLoot is the id of the button):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mundaneLoot);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class ));
        }

    });

}
```

My xml code for the pop up window (which essentially is a new activity) is:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Pop up window"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I want to edit the  `android:text="Pop up window"`  from the java code.

Comment: (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView).setText("what ever");

Comment: pop up window is a dialog ??

Comment: @SagarNayak as I've stated in my question I followed a tutorial where I create a pop up as a new activity.

Comment: So the activity in which you are showing popup is ??? and the activity from which you want to change its text is ???? (please give names of the activity )

Comment: The `Activity` he is opening in his `Intent` IS a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go on the `onCreate` method of the Pop class and then

```
TextView popUpMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
popUpMessage.setText("Example");
```

Answer (score 2):

If your pop-up dialog is an `Activity`, you can pass in a value to that `Activity` through your `Intent`. You can do so like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class);
intent.putExtra("value", randomValueFromArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can then get the value from the `Intent` in the `onCreate()` of your `Pop` class.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
editText.setText(bundle.getString("value"));
```

If you want to know how to get a random value from an `ArrayList`, you could use something like this.

```
String text = list.get((new Random()).nextInt(list.size()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use editText Like this:

```
EditText editText;
```

In on create bind the editText like this

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setText("YOUR_TEXT");
```